# SQLite: statement/transaction origin

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my DB I have two different types of statements/transactions. I want to have a way of differentiating between them.

---

This whole problem can be simplified to an example:

#### A) Internal modification

Internal mechanisms of the app cause a:

`Table A/row 1 modification`  `->` **`low`**`priority` `->` `perform action`**`A`**

#### B) External modification

**User's action** cause a:

`Table A/row 1 modification`  `->` **`high`**`priority` `->` `perform action`**`B`**

---

Both of those types can apply to all tables & all rows in the DB.

Is there some sort of a mechanism in SQLite that would allow me to track the `origin` of a statement or a transaction?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "track" where/when/how? In which situation do you want to be able to answer the question "where did this come from?" ? Can you add another column to your database "lasteditedfrom" ?

Comment: Generally speaking, I want to know that after my db is modified. How and where seems to be specific to a solution. My case is a db in Android, so if there's a solution that works is android-only, that should be fine as well. In general I have the ability to "watch" record changes in any table so for now I was considering that as the `trigger`. Adding the column was the solution that I was thinking about already, but for me it's not really implementable, due to the number of tables I would have to modify.

Comment: maybe not "as the `trigger`", but "as the `where`"

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you know a mechanism to "track ... a statement or transaction" and only ask about how to track "... the origin ..."? Then please explain that mechanism/method. Also, I recommend to add any information to the question, instead of giving it down here in the comments.

Comment: Internal or External 'events' trigger code to execute.  So, if you perform some database activity, you only need to pass along some code to the database update statement to log the source.  You could log wether it was user generated, or system generated, you could log which event handler was activated and any other specific information you wish.  I think you already know this, but your complaint is that you have too many tables you would have to update.  Maybe have a log table that you insert to first, get the key, then add one log key column to all of your other tables?